# nodemailer send mail with specific information for specific receiver

Tags: javascript, email, gmail, backend, nodemailer

i am using nodemailer to send mails to mutiple users but i got this problem, i have a json file like this:

```
[
  {
    "email": "dotam1236@gmail.com",
    "content": "this email send for dotam1236@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "email": "sale.shopeeholic@gmail.com",
    "content": "this email send for sale.shopeeholic@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "email": "ducminhtuhp@gmail.com",
    "content": "this email send for ducminhtuhp@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "email": "xrodell3@vimeo.com",
    "content": "this email send for xrodell3@vimeo.com"
  },
  {
    "email": "pbeadle4@cnet.com",
    "content": "this email send for pbeadle4@cnet.com"
  }
]
```

as you can see, there is an array of receiver and content for each email, and this is my nodemailer code:

```
  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "Gmail",
    auth: {
      user: "your@gmail.com", // please modify it into your gmail
      pass: "yourpassword!" // please modify it into your password of gmail and remove it when you success
    }
  });

  var mailOptions = {
    from: "sale.shopeeholic@gmail.com",
    to: "dotam1236@gmail.com, sale.shopeeholic@gmail.com",
    cc: "sale.shopeeholic@gmail.com",
    subject: "Test",
    text: "nodemailer send multiple receivers successfully"
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "error in sending mail", error });
    } else {
      return res.status(200).json({ message: "mail sent" });
    }
  });
```

how can i send mails for each email address in the json above with the specific content, thank you so much for helping me out, and if you dont mind, please modifiy it in the codesandbox link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nodemailer-send-multiple-receivers-illbl?file=/src/index.js:37-1164) (the server is ExpressJs but nevermind, it won't affect that much)

In that link, you should modify by your own gmail and the password of your email but i swear to God that i will never make it intrude your personal information, you can use yours and remove them when you success. once again thank you so much. hope you have a good day

Answer (score 0):

We can send multiple email at once in an array.

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
service: "Gmail",
auth: {
  user: "your@gmail.com", // please modify it into your gmail
  pass: "yourpassword!" // please modify it into your password of gmail and remove it when you success
}


});



var mailOptions = {
from: "sale.shopeeholic@gmail.com",
to: ["dotam1236@gmail.com, sale.shopeeholic@gmail.com"],
cc: "sale.shopeeholic@gmail.com",
subject: "Test",
text: "nodemailer send multiple receivers successfully"


};



transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
if (error) {
  console.log(error);
  return res.status(400).json({ message: "error in sending mail", error });
} else {
  return res.status(200).json({ message: "mail sent" });
}
  });
```